# How to avoid var's which get assigned in loops

Tags: scala, loops

I'm iterating over the command line input arguments in my Scala program and want to set several variables in a loop. My problem is that I'm using var's.

I don't want to use big libraries for this task, I want to keep it simple. The arguments contain simple key value pairs (like "-v myVar"), that's why I try to use the sliding function. Probably not the best choice for setting val's.

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // args: Array("-c", "myFile", "-j", "update", "-d", "debugPath")

    var config: String = null
    var jobType: String = null
    var debug: String = null

    args.sliding(2,2).toList.collect {
      case Array("-c", argProperty: String) => config = argProperty
      case Array("-j", argJobType: String) => jobType = argJobType
      case Array("-d", argDebug: String) => debug = argDebug
    }

    println("Config: " + config)
    println("Job type: " + jobType)
    println("Debug: " + debug)
  }
}
```

The code compiles and delivers the correct output, but the 3 var's are not so nice. However, I could not find a solution for declaring 3 val's in a loop which are used outside the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code turns your arg list in to a `Map` from argument name to value:

```
val argMap = args.grouped(2).collect{ case Array(k, v) => k -> v }.toMap

val config = argMap.getOrElse("-c", defaultConfig)
```

This avoids using `null` and allows you to easily tell whether a parameter was supplied or not.